# Django REST saves Image but returns wrong path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save Community image and it saves it to `/api/media/imagename.jpg`, but when I retrieve a community it gives me `/media/imagename.jpg` without /api and then it can't find a image.

So I have this `Community` model with `FileField`:

```py
class Community(models.Model):
    """DB Model for Community"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number_of_members = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    community_image = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, default="", upload_to="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I have this in my `settings.py`:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

And then this is in my `urls.py`:

```py
# urls.py in authentication_api application
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('communities', views.CommunityViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),  
]

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# urls.py in root urls file
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('authentication_api.urls'))
]
```

What should I change to it returns correct path to image.

If you need any more code sample please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should store media files like:

```
media/api/imagename.jpg
```

And not:

```
api/media/imagename.jpg
```

---

If you want to store like:

```
media/api/imagename.jpg
```

Then in the `community_image` field, you just need to change:

```
upload_to=""
```

To:

```
upload_to="api/"
```